# Returns false statement

Tags: excel-formula

The below gives me a FALSE statement. I took off the second “” at the end but makes no difference:

```
=IF(OR(AQ2246=0,AY2246=0),"",IF(COUNTIF(AJ$2:AJ2246,AJ2246)=1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("
(dr)",E2246)),"DR",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("(ba)",E2246)),"BA",""))))
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Please reduce this to a sample for one test on a small page and give us some test data to work with.   Use a1,a2,a3,b1 etc.  Would help.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is valid so my guess is that whatever is in AJ2246 is also present somewhere in AJ2:AJ2245.